# Drawable files name convention

Tags: android, android-layout

Are there any best practices when it comes to naming drawable xml files?

Some of my files start with "button", other with "ic", even though their pretty much the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is a standard naming convention that google follows/recommends its `ic_NAME_COLOR_SIZE.xml` for example `ic_arrow_drop_up_black_24dp.xml`

And yes of course it has to be all lowercase with no spaces.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Where can I find a source to read more on the conventions?

Answer (score 2):

```
File names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or _
```

You can specify naming rules for your project for your better understanding e.g. drawable for CheckBox can be named "checkbox_bg.png"

Answer (score 0):

ic stands for icons
you can avoid using button as a prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Try to name files so that related assets will group together inside a directory when they are sorted alphabetically. In particular, it helps to use a common prefix for each icon type. For example:

```
Icon: ic_done.png
Launcher Icons: ic_launcher_calendar.png
Menu Icons and Action bar icons: ic_menu_archieve.png
Tab icons: ic_tab_recent.png
Dialog icons: ic_dialog_date.png
```