# Picture showing error after being copied into drawable in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, frontend, android-drawable

[image]

As you can see I want to add the register button image but it's not supporting....I copied the first image and pasted in drawable worked perfectly then I tried to copy the second one but its not showing. what's the problem? how should I solve this?

I tried different images but same problem occurs...should i try to copy them at once or what?

Comment: Per https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#BitmapFile that should work just fine. Your screenshot shows that your IDE isn't autocompleting the file name, but if you manually type it out does it work? Also, what does your IDE tell you about the red squiggly line under the file name if you hover over it?

Comment: it doesn't say anything...what's the problem here...how should i make image appear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drawable files name convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805803/drawable-files-name-convention)

Answer (score 1):

try to rename your Image-file.
make it lowercase and replace the '-' by '_'.
There is an error to the image which is caused by the name.
f.e. name it like `register_button_black.png`.